# Allocation of pointers in MPI collective communications

Tags: c++, malloc, buffer, mpi, scatter

I wonder how MPI collective communications such as Bcast, Scatter, Gather etc. behave when the send buffer is allocated in root but it is not allocated in the other ranks.

For example:

```
rowptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (row_count + 1));
MPI_Scatterv(all_rows, rowCounts, rowDispls, MPI_INT, 
                    rowptr, row_count, MPI_INT, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Where `all_rows` is only allocated in `MASTER (rank == 0)` process. What is the behavior of MPI under this situation.

Or in the following case;

```
    MPI_Scatter(eCounts, 1, MPI_INT, &elm_count, 1, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

where `eCounts` is `int[]` and `elm_count` is `int`, but `eCount` is allocated only in `MASTER`.

Should I also allocate send buffers even if they are not used in other ranks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MPI 3.1 standard (chapter 5.6 page 160)

> The send buffer is ignored for all non-root processes.
>
> [...]
>
> All arguments to the function are significant on process root, while on other processes, only arguments recvbuf, recvcount, recvtype, root, and comm are significant.

Same story for `MPI_Gather()` but replace `recv*` with `send*`.

**All** arguments are significant in the case of `MPI_Bcast()` (the buffer is a send buffer on the root rank, and a receive buffer on the other ranks).